# Geany no support greek language

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, c, encoding, geany

I am using **Geany** for C programming.

My code contains some greek sentences,I set the **Default Encoding** to `GREEK(ISO-8859-7)`, but when I try to execute the program the greek letters show up like this.

What i should do to fix that?

[image]

OS:*Ubuntu 14.04.02 64 bit*  **LTS**
*Geany version*:1.23.1

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: The problem is,i don't like typing all of these stuff everytime i want to add Greek characters.Is there a more simple way?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a `printf` based code, please give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a Geany issue.

Try the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    fwprintf(stdout, L"γειά σου κόσμος\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The key line for me is `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");`. I would also revert the encoding to UTF-8.

Alternatively you can just use `printf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("γειά σου κόσμος\n");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]